# HttpcontextAccess.HttpContext.User values are reset on RedirectToAction

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to `.net Core`. I have a webApplication which uses Cookie Authentication. The login is successful and upon calling the following code the `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` is all set properly.

```
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
```

But then i am calling `RedirectToAction` most of the values of `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` is reset. Username is set to null, Claims shows 0 count, etc.

Can somebody help me with this.I am using `VS2017` with `Core 2.2`

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a simple demo that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: I got it fixed.   services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) should be specified before services.Mvc.....is called

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by looking at one  of the posts on internet.   services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) should be called before services.Mvc.....in Startup.cs